# if (x > 0) outputting 0 how to output nothing?

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I hope I haven't duplicated this topic I'm sure it's on here I just can't find it.

I have a product with a bunch of sizes, the availability of these sizes is stored in a database, e.g. 0 = none in stock, 1 and more = in stock.

When not available I'd like the size to not display in a drop down. When 1 and more are available they display... I can get the size to display when 1 or more but displays "0" when = "0" Which I understand but not sure how to not display. Think I over complicated the explanation there :S

```
$size_available = "";
$size_6w = $row["size_6w"];
$size_7w = $row["size_7w"];
$size_8w = $row["size_8w"];

$dropdown = "<select class='product-select' name='size' id='size'>";

if ($size_6w > 0) {
    $size_6w = "6w";
}
if ($size_7w > 0) {
    $size_7w = "7w";
}
if ($size_8w > 0)
    $size_8w = "8w";
}

$size=array("$size_6w","$size_7w","$size_8w");

foreach ($size as $size_available)
{
    $dropdown .= "<option value='$size_available'>$size_available</option>";
}

$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
```

Output is a simple echo:

```
echo $dropdown
```

Should I be using an else statement? If so how would you suggest I use it to output nothing?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions, I'll have a play and see how I go and also update my " to ' ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the size is greater than or equal to 1 and only then display the option to the user.

Here is how I would implement this:

```
<?php

$sizes = array(
    '6w' => $row["size_6w"],
    '7w' => $row["size_7w"],
    '8w' => $row["size_8w"]
);

$dropdown = "<select class='product-select' name='size' id='size'>";

foreach ($sizes as $size => $available)
{
    if ($available >= 1)
        $dropdown .= "<option value='$size'>$size</option>\n";
}

$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
```

Comment: I ended up going with Alex's suggested code. It worked great! Thanks Alex.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do.

```
$sizes = array();
if ($row["size_6w"] > 0) $sizes[] = '6w';
if ($row["size_7w"] > 0) $sizes[] = '7w';
if ($row["size_8w"] > 0) $sizes[] = '8w';

if (!empty($sizes)) {
    $options = "<select class='product-select' name='size' id='size'>\n";
    foreach ($sizes as $size)
        $options .= "<option value='$size'>$size</option>\n";
    $options .= "</select>\n";
} else $options = "<div id='size' class='noResult'>0</div>\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a bunch of conditions, you can write a loop that inspects particular values of `$row`:

```
// this attempts to simulate the database row data
$row = array(
        'size_6w' => 1,
        'size_7w' => 0,
        'size_8w' => 2,
        'x' => 123, // field thrown in to illustrate the workings
);

$sizes = array();
foreach ($row as $field => $value) {
        // column should start with 'size_' and the value should be more than 0
        if (0 != strncmp($field, 'size_', 5) || !$value) {
                continue;
        }
        $size = substr($field, 5);
        echo sprintf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $size, $size);
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks, I knew there would be a simpler way to do it, still getting my head around things.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($size_6w > 0) {
    $size_6w = "6w";
    array_push($size, "6w");
    }
if ($size_7w > 0) {
    $size_7w = "7w";
    array_push($size, "7w");
    }
if ($size_8w > 0) {
    $size_8w = "8w";
     array_push($size, "8w");
    }

//$size=array("$size_6w","$size_7w","$size_8w");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$size=array($size_6w,$size_7w,$size_8w);
if(!empty($size))
{
foreach ($size as $size_available)
        {
          if(!empty($size_ailvaable)
          {
            $dropdown .= "<option value='$size_available'>$size_available</option>";
          }
        }
}
}
$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
```

Comment: You shouldn't put double quotes around a variable like `"$size_6w"`.

Comment: Yeah, I was originally going to add that comment to the question, but thought it would be better on your answer.

Comment: :) he i will take care next time

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you might want change your code like this:

```
$size = array(); //initialize size array
if ($size_6w > 0) {
    $size_6w = "6w";
    $size[] = $size_6w;
}
if ($size_7w > 0) {
    $size_7w = "7w";
    $size[] = $size_7w;
}
if ($size_8w > 0) {
    $size_8w = "8w";
    $size[] = $size_8w;
}

$size=array("$size_6w","$size_7w","$size_8w"); //remove this line in your code.
```

In this way it will only include sizes into your `$size` array if its value is greater than 0.

Comment: Your logic is flawed. You're re-defining `$size` on the last line.

Comment: @Mike see the comment behind that line.